# Want to help tag MediaWiki questions?

Tags: support, tags, suggested-edits

I notice there are [many MediaWiki-related questions without a MediaWiki-related tag](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mediawiki+-%5Bmediawiki*%5D+-%5B*mediawiki%5D+-%5Bwikipedia*%5D+-%5Bwikimedia*%5D+-%5Bwikitext%5D+is%3Aquestion) (a good portion of those 500 results). Can you help adding a mediawiki tag where relevant?

[Tagged questions](https://stackexchange.com/filters/116580/mediawiki) are then [advertised to MediaWiki users](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Communication#Forums).

Comment: Be careful here; not all those 500 posts deserve a MediaWiki tag; they are *referring* to MediaWiki but are not *about* MediaWiki. The [first hit in your search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7543562/mediawiki-like-directory-system) for example refers to how MediaWiki builds URLs, and wants to replicate that pattern.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, sure, hence my "where relevant". :)

Comment: I went through all those 500 questions and tagged all the most obviously MediaWiki-related ones (about 50). For the others I appreciate second opinions. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short of bumping I guess there isn't much more to say here. I did good part of the retags in the questions backlog, more tagging polishing is of course always useful.